# Get specific file from .tar file within a Bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, extract, tar

I want to extract a specific file named `WholeImage.jpg` from a `.tar` file in Windows.

I got it working in one specific case, in which I specify the exact filelocation in the `.tar` file:

```
tar -xf %~1 --strip-components 5 InspectionProjectList/InspectionProject0718/InspectionProgram001/Sensing/Board0003/WholeImage.jpg
```

The `--strip-components 5` is to get rid of the unnecessary folders while extracting the wanted file.

However the filepath for the `WholeImage.jpg` changes from tar file to tar file.

The parts that change are noted here witd a dollar sign:

```
InspectionProjectList/InspectionProject$$$$/InspectionProgram$$$/Sensing/Board$$$$/WholeImage.jpg
```

Comment: If there's only one instance of `Wholeimage.jpg` in that archive, what's wrong with using: `@"%__AppDir__%tar.exe" -x --strip-components 5 -f "%~1" "*\WholeImage.jpg"`?

Comment: If there are several images with that name, then you may have to run `@"%__AppDir__%tar.exe" -tf "%~1" "*\WholeImage.jpg"` and pipe the results through `findstr.exe` to locate the specific item string you need first. _(this may also give you the opportunity to determine the number of directory components to strip too)_. Obviously in both examples `%__AppDir__%` assumes you're using the Windows 10 built-in `tar.exe` utility; change the location if yours is not in `\Windows\System32\ `